# Declaring 2-Dimensional arrays in Java

Tags: javac

Following are the legal array declarations:

```
int i[][];
int []j[];
int [][]k;
int[][] l;
```

But if we declare the arrays in a single line we we are getting a SYNTAX error

```
int [] []i, []j[], k[], l[][];

ERROR: Syntax Error.
```

Why is this behavior being displayed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

problem is here

```
int [] []i, []j[], k[], l[][];
            ^^
```

In Java after `,` in declaration section you are allowed to declare new variable with new additional dimensions after it, not before it, so

```
int a, b[], c[][];
```

is possible and it is the same as

```
int a;
ing[] b;
int[][] c;
```

but

```
int a, []b;
```

is incorrect.

From [jls-8.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3)

> More than one field may be declared in a single field declaration by using more than one declarator; the FieldModifiers and Type apply to all the declarators in the declaration.
>
> The declared type of a field is denoted by the Type that appears in the field declaration, **followed** by any bracket pairs that follow the Identifier in the declarator.

Additional informations are available in [10.2. Array Variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.2)

Comment: Wow, I can't believe `int a, b[], c[][];` is valid syntax.  That's gross;

Comment: @dimo414 sometimes it is useful, instead of writing `int a[][][], b[][], c[][][]` you can just write `int[][] a[], b ,c[]`.

Comment: Call me crazy, but that does not sound useful at all.

Answer (score 2):

I think the array symbols '[][]' are linked to the 'int', so
    int[][] i, j, k, l
would work

What you did is like

```
Object a, Object b, Object c;
```

Which is incorrect

instead,

```
Object a; Object b; Object c;
```

or

```
Object a, b, c
```

is correct